# C++ Programming with Curl library - Throwing error "protocol https not supported or disabled."

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I was successful in building the latest version 7.64.1 of curl library (libcurl.lib) from VC++-2010.

However, after linking the library to the release version and running the .exe, I get the error "Protocol https not supported".

Note: I was able to execute my application with old curl library. So what am I missing?

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? I'm building a real time application and experienced this error. What was wrong in posting this question? Someone may experience the same issue and find the answer helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by adding the following while building the library.

```
USE_WINDOWS_SSPI
USE_SCHANNEL
USE_SSLEAY
```